# input string was not in correct format asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a strange error. I have a page which loads values according to the country value stored in the session. it works fine for all other countries. only for particular country it is returning this error.

```
protected void populateDDMonth()
{
    int numberOfMonths;
    string monthName;
    string completeCalendarFile = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "admin\\text-files\\", calendarFile);
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(completeCalendarFile);
    date_classa = tr.ReadLine(); //Get classa end date string
    date_classb = tr.ReadLine(); //Get classb end date string
    DateTime dateConvert_classa = DateTime.Parse(date_classa); 
    DateTime dateConvert_classb = DateTime.Parse(date_classb);
    tr.Close();
    DataTable MonthTable = new DataTable();
    MonthTable.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
    MonthTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
    DateTime endMonth = DateTime.Today;
    DDMonth.Items.Clear(); //Clear dropdown in order to re-populate
    string classValue = DDClassType.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (classValue == "10" || classValue == "12" || classValue == "15")
    {
        endMonth = dateConvert_classa;
    }
    else if (classValue == "9" || classValue == "13" || classValue == "16")
    {
        endMonth = dateConvert_classb;
    }
    if (endMonth.Year > DateTime.Today.Year)
    {
        numberOfMonths = (endMonth.Month + 12) - DateTime.Today.Month;
    }
    else
    {
        numberOfMonths = endMonth.Month - DateTime.Today.Month;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonths + 1; i++)
    {
        monthName = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMM"); //Display month as 3 letter string
        DataRow MonthRow = MonthTable.NewRow();
        MonthRow[0] = monthName.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).Year.ToString();
        MonthRow[1] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString();
        DDMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(monthName.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).Year.ToString(),
        DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString()));
    }
    if (Session["selectedMonth"] != null)
    {
        DDMonth.SelectedValue = Session["selectedMonth"].ToString();
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        DateTime startingDate = DateTime.Parse(DDMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
        LbCalendarCurrentMonth.Text = startingDate.ToString("MMMM");

    }
}
```

Comment: This question is useless without code

Comment: don't post it all here. Search for the "catch" blocks and post them here, one of them is relevant. If you can debug it's great, find the exact place and post only that code.

Comment: DateTime startingDate = DateTime.Parse(DDMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
            LbCalendarCurrentMonth.Text = startingDate.ToString("MMMM");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with int casts and conversions within the International cultures:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942460

Comment: @sampath - Then why didn't you label the question JavaScript? You labeled it asp.net, doesn't it seem reasonable that you will get asp.net troubleshooting and responses?

Comment: @Joel I believe the error is from the codebehind file, but popping up as a javascript error. I checked for casting errors but everything seems fine. it works for all other inputs

Comment: @sampath - Everything may seem fine, but as you can see in the article I posted, valid inputs do not parse as expected. You may want to look at any casts you have in the code-behind and place them into Try/Catch blocks to specifically catch them and find out what inputs/resources are causing the exception. The javascript output is just one of the methods that asp.net uses to display exceptions, especially in AJAX-enabled pages.

Comment: @sampath - what is the problem? Just run debug and You will see where the error occures :/

Comment: @Joel Yes I did put them in a try/catch block but i am getting the correct values on the debugger, when i pass through the exception it gives the javascript error

Comment: @sampath - without seeing code I can't be of any further help. You're receiving a casting exception. It's just presenting itself as a JavaScript error which means it's happening at an odd time during the request life cycle. You may want to implement some form of logging to trace what instructions are being called just before the exception occurs.

Comment: @sampath - I don't know that it would be all that meaningful to mail it. You should edit your post here with what you believe to be the offending code. I would also recommend including any relevant resource information and the state of local variables when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @sampath - I meant edit the text of your question rather than posting it as comments. It's very hard to read as comments.

Comment: @sampath - there are a lot of untested datetime conversions there. I see you're using `DateTime.Parse`, but you may want to try `DateTime.TryParseExact` or even `Convert.ToDateTime` inside a Try/Catch and run a debug. This should at least give you a line-by-line analysis of which line is specifically causing this error. If it's just for one country, it's highly likely that one of your `Parse` methods is receiving an unrecognized date format for that country's locale.

Comment: @Joel thanks that's fixed. I was getting a wrong input from the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever value is selected (if any) in `DDMonth` drop down, is not a valid date.

So the following code should work without error:

```
DateTime startingDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(DDMonth.SelectedValue.ToString(), out startingDate)
{
   LbCalendarCurrentMonth.Text = startingDate.ToString("MMMM");
}
```